# Custom frame ticks in listplot

Tags: plotting, graphics

i am trying to ListPlot some data extracted from the approximation of a complicated function. The minimal code is the following

`pl[m_, n_] := ListPlot[f[m, n], PlotStyle -> Automatic, Frame->True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{{1, m},{2,m+1},{3,m+2},{4,m+3},{5,m+4},{6,m+5},{7,m+6},{8,n}}, None}}]`

The code will not run as I have not provided the function `f[m,n]` here. Why the plot is defined like that? The reason is I have to generate many plots just by changing the value of `m, n`.
Please look at the FrameTicks `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{{1, m},{2,m+1},{3,m+2},{4,m+3},{5,m+4},{6,m+5},{7,m+6},{8,n}}, None}}`, where it can be seen that I want to relabel the frameticks that way. The `m` value need not to be start from `1` always. The issue is if I increase the number of ticks say between `10 & 100`, I have to put `91` pairs `{i,m+i-1}` (in this case) using my approach as I understand that my approach is a sort of manual.
The question is how I can adjust these ticks automatically starting from prechosen `m` and ending at `n` with a step size of my choice, e.g. `1 or 2 or 5` etc.
I searched on the web, but unfortunately, I didn't see any match understandable to me. Help is needed in this regard, please.

Comment: Instead of an explicit list, you can create a Table: `Table[{i, m + i - 1}, {i, 1, n}]`? I am not sure if I understood your rules are for generating the ticks though.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community for ```pl[4,15]```, how the FrameTicks can be adjusted to be of the form ```3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 15```? I mean to start from ```3``` and end at ```15```. I need an automated code that should work for ```pl[6,20], pl[3,30]``` etc.

Comment: e.g., `m = 4; n = 9;` and `Table[{i,
  If[i == m, "m"
   , If[i == n, "n", "m+" <> ToString[i - m]
    ]]
  }, {i, m, n}
 ]` could be used as x-ticks.

Comment: @Syed Can't it take the values of m and n from ```pl[m,n]``` automatically?

Comment: You have already defined a function, so I think it can. I was trying to imagine or interpret how the ticks would look like. Try it give feedback. (Specifically, you need to write a `Module` for this function. Can you do it?)

Comment: @Syed, it don't work. It displays ```3, m+1, m+2,...,m+7,...,12``` when I insert ```pl[3,12]```

Comment: As it should: `m =3, n = 12` and the ticks are between those points. You can always make minor adjustments, if you don't like this output. You can  introduce a step size in the `Table` command as well.

Comment: @MarcoB it worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this (I introduced a local variable for clarity, and I replaced f[m,n] so I could see an actual plot)?

```
pl2[m_, n_] :=
  With[
    {ticks = Table[{i, i + m - 1}, {i, 1, n - m}]},
    ListPlot[ticks, PlotStyle -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
      FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks, None}}]]
```

Since you might want to control the spacing between ticks, it might be good to introduce another argument, like this:

```
pl2[m_, n_, step_] :=
  With[
    {ticks = Table[{i, i + m - 1}, {i, 1, n - m, step}]},
    ListPlot[ticks, PlotStyle -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
      FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks, None}}]]
```